# unable to change rabbitmq default user

Tags: spring-boot, security, rabbitmq

I am trying to connect to a rabitmq from a springbok app with a newly created user on rabbitmq but according to logs the app is always trying to connect with the default guest user

the rabbitmq logs

```
2019-02-13 00:12:38.860 [error] <0.1318.0> Error on AMQP connection <0.1318.0> (192.168.1.185:60124 -> 192.168.1.185:5672, state: starting):
PLAIN login refused: user 'guest' can only connect via localhost
```

the yaml spring boot app config

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: 111.111.111.111
    port: 5672
    username: user1
    password: user1
    connectionName: com.test.user
```

the spring boot error log

```
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.AuthenticationFailureException: ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:362)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1104)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1054)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1218)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:471)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

In the springboot app, under resources, you may create one **application.properties** file and configure the following information.

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=111.111.111.111
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=user1
spring.rabbitmq.password=user1
```

Comment: I have the configuration in yaml ... application.yaml

Comment: I refer to the official documentation from srping website, RabbitMQ configuration is controlled by external configuration properties in spring.rabbitmq.*. For example, you might declare the following section in application.properties

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html

Answer (score 0):

you may write as:

```
rabbitmq:
   config:
      host: 111.111.111.111
      port: 5672
      username: user1
      password: user1
      connectionName: com.test.user
```